# Android Studio + AVD: App crashing in emulator and logcat empty

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, logcat, android-virtual-device

I have an app that is crashing as soon as it opens in an AVD (emulator) started from Android Studio and logcat is completely empty. So, I can't locate and fix the problem.

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Hi, you might want to check that you selected the correct filter and that you chose the correct log level (verbose) for instance.

Comment: It's already set to "Show only selected application" and "Verbose". No log at all.

Comment: Perhaps you can try restarting logcat - you can press `Alt+6` twice to restart the logcat window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's stupid, but tricky. Might help others.

Android Studio is not cleaning logcat's search box during is startup. I had a string into it filtering the results for weeks and did not see that.

I've cleaned the search box and could see all the log again using the emulator normally.